# Disable button in Gridview in multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have buttons in one Column called Type. When the user clicks on the button it should be disabled. This works fine in the first page but it doesnt on the second,third,fourth pages.

I have 10 rows in my page and e.CommandArgument gets the row number.

I believe the buttons are populated in the gridview from 0 to 9 and e.CommandArgument is 1-10. Thats why I have (e.CommandArgument) - 1 and it works find in the first page.

The things that in the second page the next buttons are again 0-9 but my e.CommandArgument is 11-20. Any ideas?

```
protected void GridViewType_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{  
  Button btnVote = (Button)GridViewType.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) - 1].FindControl("btnVote");
  btnV ote.Enabled = false;

}
```

Comment: You could set the Boolean value into a session variable then read from that to determine if the buttons are enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
protected void GridViewType_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(e.CommandSource);
  Button btnVote = (Button)row.FindControl("btnVote");
  btnVote.Enabled = false;
}
```

kindly check this :

[want to Find Control in gridview on RowCommand event](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/193770/want-to-Find-Control-in-gridview-on-RowCommand-eve)

Comment: Gives Error: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'. at SWOTLine.index.GridViewType_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

Comment: gives error: Error 9 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Apollo my bad i forgot to cast the control into (Button)